# Missing rospkg dependency for ARM (Pandaboard)

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, pandaboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> *modified as a wiki after arriving at a solution*

There is a specific tutorial to install ROS Groovy on the Pandaboard.
http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source

But you could get stuck at step 3.1.2:
rosdep fails because apt-get fails installing python-rospkg (package not available).

Unfortunately some packages are missing from the apt repository and there is no way (at the moment) to solve the problem, thus what is needed is to allow rosdep to continue on errors:
`$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y -r`

Notice the -r at the end.
Rosdep should now proceed, notifying you at the end that some packages are missing

```
apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y python-rospkg] failed
apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y python-rosdep] failed
apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y python-catkin-pkg] failed
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rospkg]
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rosdep]
apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-catkin-pkg]
```

Disregarding the above warnings, you can proceed with the catkin install as detailed in the tutorial, which results in a working ros installation.
So the tutorial should be (probably) amended by making explicit that some packages are missing from the available repos and that rosdep should be run with the `-r` option to continue on errors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52595/missing-rospkg-dependency-for-arm-(pandaboard)/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that you will have better success following this guide.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/PandaBoard/Source

At the time of me writing this, the guide is still incomplete, but it seems to cover some of the hurdles that you will encounter while installing.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-01-17**:
Mjcarroll, maybe this slipped through your attention :P
The link you posted is exactly the same I posted, so I've been following that same guide.
Besides nothing can solve the fact that
sudo apt-get install python-rospkg
fails because python-rospkg is missing from my repos.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-01-17**:
So those instructions do work, and they don't tell you to do `sudo apt-get install python-rospkg`.  That should be done with pip/easy_install as armhf debs don't exist for those.  You should also use the -r flag on the rosdep command, to tell it to continue, even with errors.

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-01-17**:
both pip and easy_install fail at installing python-rospkg.
I'm now trying adding -r to rosdep.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-01-17**:
Can you post the output to `sudo pip install rospkg` or `sudo easy_install rospkg` ?

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-01-17**:
This way it works and it installs (or at least it appears to be working).
I'm going through the make process, I'll update the question once I know how it goes.